# Subset out all elements with the same name of list

Tags: r

***Data***

I have a list of lists that looks something like this:

```
sublist1 <- list(power=as.matrix(c(rnorm(10)),c(rnorm)),x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
sublist2 <- list(power=as.matrix(c(rnorm(10)),c(rnorm)),x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
sublist3 <- list(power=as.matrix(c(rnorm(10)),c(rnorm)),x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
mylist = list(sublist1,sublist2,sublist3)
```

My goal would be to pull out only the matrices named `power`

I've tried

```
mylist_power =mylist[sapply(mylist, '[', 'Power')]
```

But thats not working.

***Brownie point alert!!!***

How can I find the mean of the newly created list of matrices named power?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
mylist_power <- sapply(mylist, '[', 'power')
```

and some means:

```
sapply(mylist_power, mean) # one per matrix
sapply(mylist_power, colMeans) # for each column and each matrix
sapply(mylist_power, rowMeans) # for each row and each matrix
mean(unlist(mylist_power)) # for the whole list
Reduce(`+`, mylist_power) / length(mylist_power) # element-wise
```

Comment: ah nice! my example was a bit rudimentary the true matrices have 901 rows and 40 columns so the mean function won't work. but the first part works!

Comment: @JustinBrousseau, it works for a general mean. You didn't specify that you want means of rows or means of columns. Or perhaps you want only one number for whole `mylist_power`?

Comment: @Julius wouldn't you need 2 brackets for `sapply(mylist, '[[', 'power')` ? To generate a single matrix of the list ?

Comment: I'm looking for the mean of the matrices. So the output should be another matrix with 901 rows and 40 columns

Comment: @user5249203, true, but these matrices might have different dimensions. Also, for the element-wise mean it is more convenient to have a list of matrices.

Comment: Perfect. The element wise one is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

`purrr` solution which can be replicated to baseR's `Map`

```
#part 1 (to return only $power of every list item)
map(mylist, ~.x$power)

[[1]]
             [,1]
 [1,]  0.33281918
 [2,] -1.12404046
 [3,] -0.70613078
 [4,] -0.72754386
 [5,] -1.83431439
 [6,] -0.40768794
 [7,]  0.02686119
 [8,]  0.91162864
 [9,]  1.63434648
[10,]  0.06068561

[[2]]
             [,1]
 [1,] -0.02256943
 [2,] -0.90315486
 [3,]  0.90777295
 [4,]  1.16194290
 [5,] -0.45795340
 [6,]  0.92795667
 [7,] -2.10293514
 [8,] -1.67716711
 [9,]  1.76565577
[10,]  0.79444742

[[3]]
             [,1]
 [1,] -0.36200564
 [2,] -1.13955016
 [3,] -0.81537133
 [4,]  1.31024563
 [5,] -0.25836094
 [6,]  0.60626489
 [7,]  0.31344822
 [8,]  0.05360308
 [9,]  1.12825379
[10,] -0.55813346
```

part-2

```
map(mylist, ~.x$power %>% colMeans)
[[1]]
[1] -0.1833376

[[2]]
[1] 0.03939958

[[3]]
[1] 0.02783941
```

To get these values in a vector instead

```
map_dbl(mylist, ~.x$power %>% colMeans)
[1] -0.18333763  0.03939958  0.02783941
```